# Acrescentar informações em um mapa em SVG

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho um mapa em SVG no meu site. Eu gostaria de acrescentar uma `div` para quando o usuário passar o mouse em cima de um respectivo estado, ele mostrar o nome do mesmo.
O que acontece, é que se eu incluir qualquer informação dentro de `<svg>` os estilos se perdem. Pode ser uma `div` ou `span` acima do `<a>`.

[Mapa que utilizei](https://github.com/felipeduardo/mapa-brasil-svg/blob/master/README.md)

Meu código:

http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/g0c64uxw/

Coloquei no JSFiddle pois o código ultrapassa o limite de carácteres do snipset.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode selecionar os elementos SVG normalmente, como se fossem HTML.

Criei um exemplo, partindo do teu exemplo,  onde ele printa numa `<h3>` o atributo `xlink:href` de cada estado. [<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/g0c64uxw/1/)

Coloquei uma classe `estado-svg` em todos os estados e coloquei um *handler* do evento *mouseenter*.

```
var estados = $(".estado-svg"), // seciona todos o <a> 
    teste = $("#teste"); // seleciona o <h3> para printar os estados

/*
poderia ser usado assim:

$(".estado-svg").on("mouseenter", function(){ ... });

Mas usei delegação de eventos por questões de performance
*/

$("#svg-map").on("mouseenter", ".estado-svg", function(){
    teste.html($(this).attr('xlink:href')); // Printa no <h3> o attributo xlink:href
});
```

A partir desse exemplo já dá para ter uma ideia de como interagir com os elementos e utilizar alguma biblioteca de popover.

---

**EDIT**

[Essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic) do Stackoverflow em Inglês responde tua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. O que acontece, é que quando eu crio uma `div` dentro desse SVG, ele perde toda a formatação, mesmo eu informando corretamente a estrutura do CSS. Eu teria que informar o nome do estado dentro do `svg`.

Comment: o fato é que não existe o elemento `<div>` no SVG, tornando teu SVG inválido. Deve ser por isso que quebra o estilo. Olha a [referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG) e ache um elemento que sirva como `<div>` pra ti.

Comment: Acho que tu deve dar uma olhada no elemento `<title>` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title)

Comment: Editei a resposta dá uma olhada ali que acho que resolve teu problema.

Comment: [Um exemplo](http://www.markhansen.co.nz/stolen-vehicles-pt2/) que achei nesse link que editei.

Comment: obrigado pelos links. Sobre o código que você colocou, eu devo manter o H3 no mesmo lugar? ou devo usar outro HTML?

Comment: Eu mandei só um exemplo de como acessar o SVG por javascript... Não é necessário usar o H3 se não quiser

Comment: Ah blz. Mas esse exemplo difere um pouco do que já tenho feito. Mesmo assim, obrigado. Eu gostaria de aproveitar o que já tenho.